# Is "Community poll" a valid way of discussion in our meta?

Tags: discussion, support, community, meta

Recently I came across few questions in our meta which were "polling" in nature. I too asked my previous question of same type.

In a way such questions potentially could be close-able as "opinion based", because the answers would vary based on user's own experience. But due to their specific nature, I created a tag [poll](/questions/tagged/poll), to legitimize such posts.

A fellow user drew my attention to below posts which suggest that meta sites don't encourage polling.

- [Are poll-style questions ever acceptable on meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233908/163449)
- [Close Reason for Poll Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16399/163449)

Since the meta-s are community driven, every meta is somewhat different with common base rules.

**Questions**:

- Is polling accepted in our meta?
- Is it worth having a tag [poll](/questions/tagged/poll) for it?

Answer (score 8):

It's probably not a good idea, except for the occasional bit of amusement. Which is to say... It's fine, as long as you don't take the results seriously.

Meta sites tend to represent a somewhat skewed sample of the total membership of the site, so expecting voting on answers to a meta question to reflect the opinions is a bit dodgy at best.

On top of that... Most of us are pretty bad at constructing balanced polls; we'll usually pick options that subtly push readers toward the outcome we'd like to see.

For that reason more than any, anything even slightly serious should be posted as a discussion, with answers posted by those motivated to defend them.

#### See also: [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177550/how-is-consensus-determined-on-meta-sites)

Comment: From your answer, I understand that the non-serious polls are OK, which don't solely depend on voting. BTW, does creating tag named as "poll" mean, that the site promotes polls or it simply doesn't matter to have or not have such tag?

Comment: Probably wouldn't be useful

Comment: Jon in his answer mentioned, *"But meta (especially on beta sites) is supposed to be where participants shape the future of their sites."*